# Python : Why does removing active object from a list of selected objects return none later

Tags: python

What I'm trying to accomplish is to determine the order of selection of 2 objects
so if i have 2 objects , the list of selected objects looks like
`[bpy.data.objects['Cylinder'], bpy.data.objects['Cylinder.001']]`
But when i use this code

```
target_obj = bpy.context.active_object
cutter_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects.remove(target_obj)
print(cutter_obj)
```

It prints none
y would this happen

Comment: I don't believe the python remove method actually returns the modified list only performs the modification. As such `cutter_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects.remove(target_obj)` is being assigned the value of None from the method completion. Instead consider `my_non_act_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj != target_obj]`

Comment: @Ratt silly me
Thnk you for that

Comment: @Ratt can u also tell me how do i add a modifier to an object if i have its name or the object in the form of `<class 'bpy_types.Object'>`

Comment: Please edit your question for a full reference of what you are attempting to accomplish or post a new question so that future users can search for a complete question and answer without reading through all comments.